# Is it valid HTML to use input elements without id and name attribute only?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I'm reworking a site which uses inputs like this multiple times throughout a page:

```
 <input type="text" name="delDate" value="06.03.2012" />
```

There's always an adjacent hidden input, which gives the date enterted above a specific id, when the form is submitted, but I'm wondering if doing it like this (and omitting an input#id is a valid way doing things, since the W3C validator does not complain about it.

Thanks for some input!

Comment: `id` for form elements is usually used to attach `label` to corresponding form element. `id` itself is not required for form elements to function or be valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is valid. The `id` attribute is not required.

Comment: but if I want a label to go with it, I need to add an id, correct? Or can I just omit the for attribute on the label

Comment: @frequent: You can also use `<label>MyLabel: <input .../></label>`, see [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL).

Comment: @alex: ok. good. I don't like this of doing it, but for the moment I need to get the code valid, next accessible. Thx for helping!

Answer (score 2):

The problem of doing this is not that it is a validity problem but that it creates an accessibility problem (i.e., it may confuse screen readers for disabled users). It is generally considered best to have a label with a "for" attribute that matches the "id" attribute of the associated input element.

Comment: thanks for the info. I was afraid of something like this, but for the time being, I have to omit the for label.